# Creating a trigger on Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to create a trigger that `updates` another table whenever the trigger table has an `insert into` command, or an `after insert trigger`.

I need to pull the id that's being inserted into the table in order to update the other table, how do I go about doing so?

---

In case that's confusing, another attempt at my question:

`Table 1` has an `after insert trigger`.  Said `trigger` updates `table 2` based on one of the id values being inserted into `table 1`.  How do I pull said id value from `table 1` in the `trigger`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :new in your trigger to reference the values being inserted, for example

```
create or replace trigger <trigger_name>
after insert on <table_name>
for each row
declare
    l_id number;
begin
    select :new.id into l_id from dual;
    -- now l_id contains the id of the inserted row, do what you want with it
end;
```

Don't take the example to literally; you don't have to first select :new.id into a variable, you can use it directly in SQL inside the trigger. I did it here just for illustration.

Take a look at the Oracle docs: [Coding Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm)

However, you might also want to take a look at some arguments why you should think twice if you really need to put your logic into triggers: [The Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

Comment: Oh no this is for an assignment, required to use only a trigger.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER testempdel
    AFTER insert ON testemp
     FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        update  testdelvalues set salary=:New.sal;
    END;
    /

Trigger created.
```

Initially the salary is null

```
SQL> select * from testdelvalues;

     EMPNO EMPNAME        SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
```

After inserting the value in the other table is updated

```
SQL> insert into testemp (empno,ename,sal) values (1231,'TESTUSER',1000);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from testdelvalues;

     EMPNO EMPNAME        SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH            1000
```